# Return values that are missing in one of the two variables R

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

My dataset is of course much larger but the principle is the same:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(Name1 = c("Joe", "Harry", "Jane", NA, NA),
       Name2 = c("Joe", "Harry", "Thomas", "Bill", "Jane"))
```

- **Question 1**: How can I extract the values in `Name2` (`"Thomas"` and
  `"Bill"`) who are missing in `Name1`?
- **Question 2**: How can I paste these values (`"Thomas"` and `"Bill"`)
     where the values in `Name1` stop beneath `"Jane"`?

Is this doable in a tidyverse kind of way?

Comment: Yes good one I edited my question

Comment: Do the names in `Name1` need to match `Name2`? i.e. should the resulting data frame be `df = tibble(Name1=c('Joe', 'Harry', 'Thomas', 'Bill', 'Jane'), Name2=c(''Joe', 'Harry', 'Thomas', 'Bill', 'Jane'))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first Question:

```
setdiff(df$Name2, df$Name1)
```

Gives you the names that do not occur in Name1. This does the same:

```
df$Name2[!df$Name2 %in% df$Name1]
```

You could now just plug the missing values in the data frame (question 2):

```
df$Name1[is.na(df$Name1)] <- setdiff(df$Name2, df$Name1)
```

Or:

```
df$Name1[is.na(df$Name1)] <- df$Name2[!df$Name2 %in% df$Name1]
```

If you want a tidyverse/dplyr-solution, this does the same:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(Name1 = ifelse(is.na(Name1), Name2[!Name2%in%Name1], Name1))
```

But in general, I don't get the big picture of what you are doing. Since you put these vectors in a data frame, both vectors need to be of same length. Furthermore, you obviously don't care about the order, you just want the names in there, which implies, given the same length, same names. Hence you could just overwrite one with the other...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `data.table` here

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

df <- tibble(Name1 = c("Joe", "Harry", "Jane", NA, NA),
         Name2 = c("Joe", "Harry", "Thomas", "Bill", "Jane"))

df <- data.table(df)

df[is.na(Name1), "Name1"] <- df[!Name2 %in% Name1, "Name2"]
df
    Name1  Name2
1:    Joe    Joe
2:  Harry  Harry
3:   Jane Thomas
4: Thomas   Bill
5:   Bill   Jane
```

Comment: Im able to use the column names directly - tried without `data.table` but doesn't give results

Comment: @brittenb: can you help me understand if there's anything missing here - I'll correct my mistake

Comment: @Hardikgupta a) my output from running your code does not match. b) doing it like this isn't scalable, if you have 3 NA values in `Name1` and 1 NA value in `Name2` I'm pretty sure the logic fails.

Comment: I don’t know why you wouldn’t be able to use the column names directly without `data.table`; that’s a feature available in base R.

Comment: @Mako212 - Your name1 might be containing string NA not `NA`

Comment: @brittenb - Removing the line which converts to data.table, I receive this error `Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'Name2' not found`

Comment: @Hardikgupta That would address the first part, my comment stands about the second part

Comment: @Mako212 - the user hasn't mention anything regarding the lengths, if there's a better answer, i'll delete mine. meanwhile I am looking for a foolproof

Comment: Oh, right, I see. Still though, there's no need to load an entire package just to be able to write `Name2` instead of `df$Name2`.

Comment: thanks brittenb, I'll take a note of this and will be careful in future

Comment: @brittenb how would you write the code without data.tables? I'm curious, I don't get it to work with the `$` syntax.

Comment: `df$Name1[is.na(df$Name1)] = df$Name2[!df$Name2 %in% df$Name1]`

Comment: @Tdebeus - What is the issue with my answer?

Comment: Nevermind your answer is great, but I mean you're now 'commenting' on the answer Hardik gupta. If you 'answer' on my question I can accept yours and you'll earn points. Anyways thanks for your solution 

Comment: I am commenting to seek if there's an issue which I can fix. The power to accept remains in your hands. As brittenb answered, you can update the line without using data table